# Yocto recipe for an application that uses opencv and cpp

Tags: c++, opencv, header, yocto

I created a recipe for a cpp application using opencv to stream an image. But The build fails with following error :

Log data follows:

```
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| shot.cpp:1:10: fatal error: core.hpp: No such file or directory
|     1 | #include "core.hpp"
|       |          ^~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

Although, I added the meta-openembedded/meta-oe that includes opencv folder in which I found core.hpp to bblayers.

Here is the recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION   = " this is an application display an image"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://shot.cpp"


DEPENDS = "opencv"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile () {
    ${CXX} shot.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio
}

do_install () {

        install -d 0755 ${D}/${bindir}
    install -m 0755  ${D}/${bindir}
}
```

When I ran the application using the opencv I installed on my ubuntu 18.04. it works fine (using cmake).

I tried adding manually the core folder next to the recipe and it didn't work of course, I also added the path of the core.hpp to the recipe in the SRC_URI variable but no luck whatsoever
I don't know what to do specially that I'm new to both yocto and opencv; help please

Here is the source code of the application:

```
#include "core.hpp"
#include "highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( )
{

      Mat image;

      // LOAD image
      image = imread("image1.jpg");   // Read the file "image.jpg".

      if(! image.data )  // Check for invalid input
      {
             cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
             return -1;
      }

      //DISPLAY image
      namedWindow( "window"); // Create a window for display.
      imshow( "window", image ); // Show our image inside it.

      waitKey(0);                       // Wait for a keystroke in the window
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need some modifications on your recipe:

```
[...]
inherit pkgconfig
DEPENDS = "opencv"
[...]
```

And you will need to add a RDEPENDS and FILES variable:

```
[...]
DEPENDS = "opencv"
# Add the runtime dependencies
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "libopencv-core libopencv-imgproc libopencv-highgui libopencv-videoio libopencv-imgcodecs"

[...]
# At the end, ship the files
FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}"
```

`RDEPENDS_${PN}` will tell Yocto that your recipe package `${PN}` needs a list a runtime dependencies. These dependencies are requiered to run your application on your board (typically libraries).

`FILES_${PN}` will tell Yocto that your recipe package `${PN}` will contains files. Without this line, Yocto will tell you that

`${PN}` is by default your recipe file name (without the version and `.bb`)

---

There is also some errors.

The compilation had some issues, lopencv_imgcodecs was not added, and there was no output name of your binary (I have named it `shot`):

```
do_compile () {
    ${CXX} ${WORKDIR}/shot.cpp -o ${WORKDIR}/shot -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs ${LDFLAGS}
}
```

The second install command is not right:

```
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/shot ${D}/${bindir}
```

Your application does not have the correct headers:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

---

At the end, the recipe looks like:

```
DESCRIPTION   = " this is an application display an image"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://shot.cpp"

inherit pkgconfig
DEPENDS = "opencv"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "libopencv-core libopencv-imgproc libopencv-highgui libopencv-videoio libopencv-imgcodecs"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile () {
    ${CXX} ${WORKDIR}/shot.cpp -o ${WORKDIR}/shot -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs ${LDFLAGS}
}

do_install () {
    install -d 0755 ${D}/${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/shot ${D}/${bindir}
}

FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}"
```

And the application:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( )
{

      Mat image;

      // LOAD image
      image = imread("image1.jpg");   // Read the file "image.jpg".

      if(! image.data )  // Check for invalid input
      {
             cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
             return -1;
      }

      //DISPLAY image
      namedWindow( "window"); // Create a window for display.
      imshow( "window", image ); // Show our image inside it.

      waitKey(0);                       // Wait for a keystroke in the window
      return 0;
}
```

The recipe was working on my Yocto warrior meta.

Comment: Hi Pierre Olivier, Thank you so much for your answer, it is really well explained. I will apply it right away

Comment: I changed the recipe and the source code as above but I still get this error :  fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory 
    1 | #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"                                  I'm on branch master where opencv version is 4.4 I don't know if this has something to do with it ( I tried it also with dunfell and I got the same error)

Comment: @bz-a I tested again with another meta on Pyro branch, and it worked. Can you build OpenCV first by running `bitbake opencv` ? You are on the master branch of which repo?  If you use Yocto, all your metas must be on the same branch (Pyro,  Rocko, Sumo,...).

Comment: Hi PierreOlivier I changed the branch to warrior and I applied the new recipe you gave me and it works ^^ thank you so much. I'm not sure I understand why when we change the branch from master or dunfell to warrior it works but I guess is about the way that bitbake handles the dynamic library linking... Do you have any idea ?

Comment: there is also one other solution : when using cmake and not manually adding libraries it works, I don't know why